# What is the Bash DEFAULTS "domain" for changing [accessibility > display > colour Filters > tint]?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, settings, defaults

I want to write some bash-scripts that change for me **system settings** like:

- accessibility > display > colour Filters > tint

What's in general the best way to find that "domain" (not sure how this thing after the defaults command is called)

(Mac OS Montery)

Answer (score 1):

To find a specific domain, type in Terminal:
`defaults find` + (the domain you are looking for)

You can access the manual by typing:
`man defaults`
to get a general idea on the defaults command

To get a complete list of the domains, type:
`defaults domains`
the list of domains will show up: there are a lot!